# JWT Bearer Authentication and Authorization not working, because of TokenValidationParameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make WEB API using .NET Core 3.1 and make Client Application that uses that API for all the server stuff. for the Client App I am using ASP .Net Core 3.1 MVC.
On my API I am trying to make JWT Bearer Authentication and Authorization.

`JwtAuthenticationService.cs` is a class I made to generate Token.

```
public async Task<String> GenerateJsonWebToken(ApplicationUser appUser)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, appUser.UserName),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Nbf, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString())
    };

    var roleNames = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(appUser);

    foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roleName));
    }
  

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        new JwtHeader(
            new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:SecretKey"])),
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)),
        new JwtPayload(claims));
            
    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

This is my Login controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] POCOUser pocoUser)
{
    IActionResult response = Unauthorized();

    var appUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(pocoUser.UserName);
    
   
    if ( await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(appUser, pocoUser.Password))
    {
        var tokenString = _jwtAuthenticationService.GenerateJsonWebToken(appUser);
        return Ok(new { token = tokenString });
    }

    return response;
}
```

I managed to determine that the problems is in my TokenValidationParameters

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false, // If I change to true it stops working
                    ValidateAudience = false, // if I change to true it stops working.
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:SecretKey"])),
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });
```

When I change to true of these parameters `ValidateIssuer` or `ValidateAudience` the API does not give me access to the controller and redirects me.

This is my appsettings.json

```
"Jwt": {
    "SecretKey": "SomeSecretKey",
    "Issuer": "https://localhost:44393/",
    "Audience": "https://localhost:44301/"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I change to true of these parameters ValidateIssuer or ValidateAudience the API does not give me access to the controller and redirects me.

Because there is no `Issuer` and `Audience` in the generated token.

If you want to change to the true of `ValidateIssuer` or `ValidateAudience`,change like below:

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
    _config["Jwt:Audience"],
    claims: claims,
    expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:SecretKey"])),
        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
```

Answer (score 2):

You must include the token when you call that endpoint because it is now protected. You can either get your token in your browser's localstorage or cookies depending on how you store it.

Then place your token here:

[image]

Add `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]` on top of your Login controller to check headers with Bearer tokens.

Comment: Well it still not working, can the problem be because I use identity for the login/reg functionality ?  
This is what I get when I make Post request to the login controller in the API https://imgur.com/a/fKX0ttH

Comment: Did you have authentication scheme = "Bearer" in your API? kindly try it.